# WooCommerce - Check if the products in a specific order are Featured

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, orders

I am trying to display a specific string with respect to a certain list of "Processing" orders that contain "Featured" product(s).

More precisely, I want to echo a message when 2 conditions are cumulatively met:

1) the order status is "processing"; and

2) ALL the products in that respective order are marked as "Featured".

In other words, once all the ordered products are manually marked by me as "Featured", a specific message should be echoed on my user's account page.

My code so far (but not giving me the desired result):

```
    <?php 

  foreach ( $order_summary as $order ) :

                            $order      = wc_get_order( $order->order_id );
                            $order_id       = $order->get_id();
                            $order_items    = get_products_for_order( $order_id );

                        if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) {
                            if ( $order_items->is_featured() ) {
                                echo 'Something';
                            } else {
                                echo 'Something else';
                            }
                        }

    ?>
```

I'm not sure how to properly check if there are (or aren't) "Featured" products in the respective order.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the `get_products_for_order()` function return? If it's an array of products, you'll need to run a foreach loop on those products before checking `is_featured()`

Comment: @johnnyd23, I am actually making some changes to a marketplace plugin. The get_products_for_order() function is as follows: 
`public static function get_products_for_order( $order_id ) {global $wpdb;$vendor_products = array(); $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT product_id
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}pv_commission WHERE order_id = {$order_id}
AND status != 'reversed'
AND vendor_id = " . get_current_user_id() . "
GROUP BY product_id" );
foreach ( $results as $value ) {$ids[ ] = $value->product_id;} return $ids;}`

Can you please help me? I can't get the hang of it. Also, @loictheaztec?

Answer (score 0):

The `get_products_for_order()` function returns an array of products. You will need to run a foreach loop on that array and check if each product is featured individually.

```
<?php 

    foreach ( $order_summary as $order ) {

        $order = wc_get_order( $order->order_id );
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $order_items = get_products_for_order( $order_id );

        if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) {

            foreach( $order_items as $item ) {

                if ( $item->is_featured() ) {

                    echo 'Something';

                } else {

                    echo 'Something else';

                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Edit after comment:

```
<?php 

    foreach ( $order_summary as $order ) {

        $order = wc_get_order( $order->order_id );
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $order_items = get_products_for_order( $order_id );

        if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) {

            $featured = true;
            foreach( $order_items as $item ) {

                if ( !$item->is_featured() ) {
                    $featured = false;
                    break;
                }                     
            }

            if( $featured ) {
                echo 'Something';
            } else {
                echo 'Something else';
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I think I've already tried this, but it's not properly working and is not giving me what I want anyways. I'll try to be more clear about my objective: I just want to echo something when 2 conditions are cumulatively met: 1) the order status is "processing"; 2) ALL the products in that respective order are marked as "Featured". In other words, once all the ordered products are manually marked by me as "Featured", a specific message should be echoed on my user's account page.

Comment: Your updated answer is not working quite well, in the sense that, irrespective if I mark the products as Featured or Not, it always echoes 'Something' and never 'Something else'.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, can you please help?

Comment: there is no function like : get_products_for_order()